# Another Perpetual Riley Riddle

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme, acrostic

As always, good luck to all of you!

> Very odd is the suffix, tis spelled the wrong way; a few letters missing, opposing day.
>
> After the prefix, the infix you'll find; if only, if only, you use your mind.
>
> Search for the prefix, found in this line; look even further, found within time.
>
> Together you'll see, something quite great; simply enough, it looks like an eight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you

> Infinite

Very odd is the suffix, tis spelled the wrong way; a few letters missing, opposing day.

> Nite

After the prefix, the infix you'll find; if only, if only, you use your mind.

> If

Search for the prefix, found in this line; look even further, found within time.

> In

Together you'll see, something quite great; simply enough, it looks like an eight.

> The sign for Infinite is infinity which is a 8 on it's side!

Acrostic

> Vast=infinite

Comment: I like this answer, although your infix appears in the word backwards... (+1)

Comment: Maybe that's why you use your mind? Lol, I don't know :D and thanks :)

Comment: WOOOOOO! I knew I made this one too simple lol but great job QuantumnTwinkie!